# Way to stop ASI on Node.js and have it err?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know automatic semi-colon injection is a contentious issue but I would prefer if I could disable it on my Node.js based server.

Script:

```
var foo = bar()
var baz = foo+1;
```

With result:

```
[Error] Expected ';' before var on line #2
```

Or anything similar.

Comment: ASI is part of the language spect, so I doubt you can disable it.

Comment: @bfavaretto I was afraid of that.

Comment: Argh, there is an extra t on my spec! :) And this is a good question, if there is a way to do that, I'll definitely try it too.

Comment: ...is this not solved by running JSHint? Have it run on save (and ideally in your editor as well.) It seems like you're just pushing a solved problem further down the chain.

Comment: +1 on JSHint/JSLint. They check for undesired coding practice for you. There are plugins for many editors to do live checking and highlighting for you.

Comment: I don't see why this has attracted 3 close votes.

Comment: @bfavaretto `"use strict"` is also part of the language spec; but it doesn't disable semi-colon insertion. Perhaps there is another option, `"no asi"` in there? Perhaps there is a way to opt-out of all the bad things in the language?

Comment: @IanBoyd That would be impossible, because "all the bad things" is subjective. `"use strict"` removes part of the bad stuff, but there's nothing in the spec to disable ASI. It could be implemented, but it would be non-standard (perhaps a flag to node).

Comment: @bfavaretto [We can all agree on some of the basic bad parts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook#t=751): global varibles, `+` concatenates, semicolon insertion, `with` and `eval`, arrays that aren't, incorrect results of `typeof`, `==` and `!=` doing type coersion, statement labels, expression statements, empty statements. At least ways to disable those would be great; without having to use a lint.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks basic understanding of ECMA script

Comment: @Matt: Maybe those close-votes were automatically inserted due to it being syntactically valid to do so

Comment: @MarkKCowan: that seems more of an answer, rather than a close reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, ASI is part of the EMCAScript specification, it can't be disabled.

Also as mentioned JSHint is a good solution, I use sublime text 2 with the "Sublime Linter" plugin, which lints your code as your code as you type.

If you really wanted to lock your server down, you could add an alias to "node" which does something like "lint file && node file", that way node wouldn't run unless lint was successful.